# Why $|\nabla \xi|<\frac{C}{r}$ in this proof.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I found this on MSE : [Prove $\int_{B(x,r)}|\nabla u|^2\leq \frac{C}{r^2}\int_{B(x,2r)}|u|^2$ if $-\Delta u(x)+f(x)u(x)=0.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2087724/prove-int-bx-r-nabla-u2-leq-fraccr2-int-bx-2ru2-if-del)

And I was wondering why in the proof of @xpaul we can choose $\xi$ as $|\nabla \xi|\leq \frac{C}{r}$ ? I'm studing partition of unity, but I don't see such a result.

Comment: Have you read the comments on @xpaul's answer? He explained why he chose that. Simply put, it is a test function, so you are free to impose conditions on it arbitrarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose $\xi \in C_c^\infty$ such that $0 \le \xi \le 1$, $\xi \equiv 1$ on $B(0,1)$, $\xi \equiv 0$ outside $B(0,2)$. Then $|\nabla \xi|$ is bounded by some constant $C$ (this constant can be taken arbitrarily close to $1$, but this is not important here).

Now let $\xi_r(x) = \xi(x/r)$. This function satisfies: $0 \le \xi_r \le 1$, $\xi_r \equiv 1$ on $B(0,r)$, $\xi_r \equiv 0$ outside $B(0,2r)$, moreover $|\nabla \xi_r| \le C/r$ (with $C$ as above).

The right phrase to search would be "cut-off function".

Comment: thank you, it's a very nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

One way to see the general idea is that if a smooth function $\xi$ has to go from taking the value $1$ at a point $x_1$ to taking the value $0$ at another point $x_0$ with $|x_0 - x_1| = r$, then $|\nabla \xi|$ will need to be at least $r^{-1}$ somewhere between $x_1$ and $x_0$. If this were not the case, then you could use the fundamental theorem of calculus along the line from $x_0$ to $x_1$ to get a contradiction.

The flip side is that you really can construct a smooth function that does this interpolation and satisfies $|\nabla \xi| \leq 2r^{-1}$.